# Error when trying to use puts in TCL/Expect

Tags: tcl, expect

I have the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeRegex "pengbumm"
expect {
   default { puts "nicht gefunden" }
   -re $timeRegex { puts "gefunden" }
}
```

If I execute it like this I get an error:

```
martin:/tmp$ echo "pengibumm" |./bla.exp
error writing "stdout": bad file number while executing
"puts "nicht gefunden" "
invoked from within
"expect {
     default { puts "nicht gefunden" }
     -re $timeRegex { puts "gefunden" }
 }"
 (file "./bla.exp" line 4)
 martin:/tmp$ echo "pengbumm" |./bla.exp
 gefunden
 martin:/tmp$
```

Why the heck does one puts work and the other doesn't? And how can I fix this?

I am guessing it has something to do with all the input being consumed, but that certainly should not stop puts from working.

Comment: The first step to debugging an expect script is _always_ to turn on a printed trace of what it is doing with `exp_internal 1`.

Comment: Just updated my answer. See if it can help.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `expect` closes `stdout` when it get `EOF` from `stdin` in this scenario:

```
$ echo | expect -c 'expect eof { puts eof }'
error writing "stdout": bad file number
    while executing
"puts eof "
    invoked from within
"expect eof { puts eof }"
$
```

Not sure if this is a bug but usually `expect` is not used this way without `spawn`ing a process.

#### UPDATE:

Just found a workaround. You can `puts` to `stderr` instead of `stdout`:

```
$ echo | expect -c 'expect eof { puts stderr eof }'
eof
$
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `expect` assumes channel input/output pairs cannot be uni-directional, so `expect_user` closes both stdin and stdout after it receives EOF on stdin.  While this makes sense for most `spawn`ed commands, it doesn't make sense for the current script's stdin/stdout.

In addition to pynexj's workaround (using `puts stderr` for output, since stderr isn't closed by `expect_user` when it receives EOF on stdin), it looks like you can use Tcl `gets` or `read` commands instead of `expect_user` to work around this:

```
set input [read stdin]
if [regexp {pengbumm} $input] then {
  puts "nicht gefunden"
} else {
  puts "gefunden"
}
```